# Backbone model change event only fires once

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, events, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a Backbone model that fires a function upon change.. I want to link that function to a view..

Model:

```
class App.Models.Tracker extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot : '/api/trackers'

  initialize: ->
    @on('change', @update, this)


  update: ->
    console.log('changed in model')
    @trigger('update', this);
```

View:

```
class App.Views.Tracker extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['trackers/tracker']

  initialize: () ->
    @model.on("update", @animate, this);

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(tracker: @model))
    this

  animate: ->
    console.log('changed in view')
    progress = @model.get('progress')
    console.log(progress)
```

What is happening is that the "update" method in model gets called every time when the model changes. But the "animate" method in view is only called once, when the model is created..

What am I getting wrong?

***EDIT***

Maybe I am just testing it wrong??

```
 trackers = new App.Collections.Trackers
 trackers.fetch()
 tracker = trackers.get(333)
 tracker.set({progress : 70})
```

333 is the id of the tracker created... But the above does not work.. JSFiddle indeed works fine, which is confusing

Comment: Why can't you just listen for the 'change' event on your model in your view?

Comment: I updated the question with how I am testing it.. maybe a mistake is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait until the `Collection.fetch()` has finished to start playing with the Models in the Collection:

```
trackers = new App.Collections.Trackers
trackers.fetch({
  success: function(){
    tracker = trackers.get(333);
    tracker.set({progress : 70});  
  }
});
```